# Unable to deploy to docker when attempting to run a spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, gradle

I am learning how to write Spring boot applications, and deploying it to Docker using gradle. I am able to run the Spring boot application with Gradle, but not with Docker **AND** Gradle. Any assistance would be appreciated. I am using Spring's git repo as my guide. https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot-docker/blob/master/complete

When I execute the following command,

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -t com.iheartmedia/iheartdemo
```

Error Message

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"gradle\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

I installed gradle with Homebrew, and this is my gradle set up

```
find / -name 'gradle' -type f

/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/5.0/bin/gradle
/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/5.0/libexec/bin/gradle
```

Gradle set up

```
which gradle

/usr/local/bin/gradle
```

Gradle command to build docker

```
./gradlew build docker

Starting a Gradle Daemon, 3 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Task :test
objc[14153]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x10dc4a4c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x10dce24e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2018-12-09 03:26:56.494  INFO 14153 --- [      Thread-92] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Closing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@389f0591: startup date [Sun Dec 09 03:26:55 PST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-12-09 03:26:56.498  INFO 14153 --- [      Thread-92] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
2018-12-09 03:26:56.499  INFO 14153 --- [      Thread-92] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-12-09 03:26:56.500  INFO 14153 --- [      Thread-92] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-22 - Shutdown initiated...
2018-12-09 03:26:56.500  INFO 14153 --- [      Thread-92] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-22 - Shutdown completed.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 49s
10 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 3 up-to-date
```

Docker file

```
FROM java:8
VOLUME /tmp
ARG DEPENDENCY=target/dependency
# Installed with homebrew with a symlink
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","com.iheartmedia.IHeartMedia"]
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE")
        classpath('gradle.plugin.com.palantir.gradle.docker:gradle-docker:0.13.0')
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven'
    id 'io.franzbecker.gradle-lombok' version '1.14'
}

apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin
apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'com.palantir.docker'

bootJar {
    baseName = 'iheartdemo'
    version =  '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url = 'http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2'
    }
}

springBoot {
    mainClassName = 'com.iheartmedia.IHeartMedia'
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.2"
    reportsDir = file("$buildDir/reports/jacoco")
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination file("${buildDir}/reports/coverage")
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-web:5.0.9.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.0.5.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.0.5.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4'
    compile 'org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.2.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2'
    compile 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2'
    runtime 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.197'
    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.0.5.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.0.5.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.0.5.RELEASE'
}

group = 'com.iheartmedia'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
targetCompatibility = '1.8'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

task unpack(type: Copy) {
    dependsOn bootJar
    from(zipTree(tasks.bootJar.outputs.files.singleFile))
    into("build/dependency")
}
docker {
    name "${project.group}/${bootJar.baseName}"
    copySpec.from(tasks.unpack.outputs).into("dependency")
    buildArgs(['DEPENDENCY': "dependency"])
}
// end::task[]
```

My Spring boot application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(considerNestedRepositories = true)
public class IHeartMedia {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(IHeartMedia.class, args);
    }
}
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated. I have looked at other SO posts but they seem to be specific to Python, Go or Node JS.

Gradle is defined in my path variable so I don't know why this might be the case. This is my PATH set up

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin/gradle:$PATH
export PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the following line in your `Dockerfile`:

```
CMD ["gradle", "/usr/local/bin/gradle"]
```

This is telling Docker to run Gradle inside the container where it does not exist. Remove this line from your `Dockerfile` as Gradle should be run outside the container. This will also align your `Dockerfile` with the file in the guide that you are following.

When Gradle is run, it will produce the artifacts that are added to the container by the following lines:

```
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
```

Comment: If you removed the line as suggested and Docker is still failing with the same error then there is something else going on that you have not described. Docker won’t try to run `gradle` when building an image unless you have told it to do so.